# pro = pro*(x[ip] - x[ir]) giving tuple index out of range error new to python

Tags: python-2.7, compiler-errors, tuples

This is the code and please help I'm getting **tuple index out of range error** in line 19

```
import math
n = 7
x = 0.5,1.2,2.1,2.9,3.6,4.5,5.7
y = 3.2,5.2,9.3,14.6,20.5,30.1,45.2
xx = 3.4
yy = y[0 ]
fact = 1
for i in range(0,n):
    fact = fact*(xx - x[i])
    s = 0.0
    i1 = i+ 2
    for ip in range(0,i1):
        pro = 1.0
        for ir in range(0,i1):
            if (ir == ip): continue
            pro = pro*(x[ip] - x[ir])
        s = s + y[ip]/pro
    yy = yy + s*fact
print "x=%5.2f      y=%5.2f"  %(xx,yy)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `i1 = i + 2` in your loop. Since i runs from 0 to n, i1 is set to values larger than the length of `x`. If you put a

```
print i1
```

before the `for ip`, you can see exactly where it goes wrong.